# Google Play Services BaseGameUtils gradle build failing

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, google-play-services

I'm using BaseGameUtils in a libgdx project to add Google play services into my game, however when I try to build the app either debug or release it fails with the following error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':BaseGameUtils:extractDebugeAnnotations'.
> originalComplianceLevel

It gives no further details on the error or how to fix it and I'm fairly new to gradle. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Had the same error yesterday, still didn't figure out how to fix it